# How do I make a html.checkboxfor checkbox larger?

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox, razor-pages

Trying to put a checkbox on a razor page and everything is working except the size. I have tried adding html attributes of @style to set width and height. I tried putting it in a div around the checkbox.

```
  <label for="FluidAbsorbtion" class="col-form-label">Fluid Absorbtion 50 lbs X 2</label>
  <div class="form-control">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FluidAbsorbtion)
  </div>
```

[image: It just ends up looking like this:]

I just need it to be a bit larger.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Steve, which version of asp.net are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: add `@style` in your `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`

```
<label for="FluidAbsorbtion" class="col-form-label">Fluid Absorbtion 50 lbs X 2</label>
  <div class="form-control">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FluidAbsorbtion,new{ @style="width:20px;height:20px;" })
  </div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: That worked.  I was adding the style wrong.  Thank you.